# Plotting Time Series data in Python Bokeh

Tags: python, pandas, plot, time-series, bokeh

I am plotting Time series data set with Bokeh.

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.charts import TimeSeries, output_notebook, show, output_file
df = pd.read_csv('Land_Ocean_Monthly_Anomaly_Average.csv')
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df[['anomaly','datetime']]
output_notebook()
```

*BokehJS successfully loaded.*

```
t = TimeSeries(df, x='datetime')
show(t)
```

This is the error message displayed

*Javascript error adding output!*

*Error: Plot.set('css_classes'): css_classes wasn't declared*

*See your browser Javascript console for more details.*

A new tab also opens up in my browser with this error message

*Bokeh Error
Plot.set('css_classes'): css_classes wasn't declared*

This is actually sample code from their tutorials. Not sure why it does not work.

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

I tried reinstalling bokeh and there is a new error message in a pop up tab in the browser

*Bokeh Error
Module `LegendItem' does not exists. The problem may be two fold. Either a model was requested that's available in an extra bundle, e.g. a widget, or a custom model was requested, but it wasn't registered before first usage.*

Comment: Did you manage the issue? I would rather to approach the problem converting the date column to date format instead use the TimeSeries function.